# Can excel fill in certain fields based on variables from a website?

Tags: javascript, excel, e-commerce, vba

Our ecommerce platform will does not currently create invoices. I have an invoice template that I currently use in excel, so I essentially just copy and paste about 8 points of data from the ecommerce platform to the spreadsheet, then print it out.

Even though the ecommerce platform does not create invoices, that data can be sent anywhere I would like, including a website or email, so I've used it to automatically notify me of certain purchases via email.

What I am wondering is since the variables (eg. user_address) are always the same that are sent from the platform, can that information somehow be sent to an excel spreadsheet (my template), which will then be populated by the appropriate variables, so all that's left to do is print it out?

I'm not really a programmer, so any code snippets you can provide or some idea of whether or not this will take a programmer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check out [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/), this would let you create something in Java, perhaps a servlet, that would catch the data from your ecommerce app and make a spreadsheet.

Alternatively you could make a Google Spreadsheet and an associated form and write some intermediary script in whatever language you like that will send the right post variables to the Google form from the ecommerce app. I would expect this solution to be much less involved.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at APIs like JExcel, which lets you read/write cells of an Excel file using Java. If you send your data to an Excel file, and then pull it out using this package, you could get the desired results. You may still need a programmer for this method, although there would not be a lot of work involved.